# Pandas dataframe columns data type got changed for Null Mysql columns Values from Int to Float

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pandas

I'm creating a dataframe using python panadas by reading a Mysql table.
In that I have few columns with `INT` data type but has `null` values in it.  When I create a dataframe all those columns' datatypes are changed to float and `null` values are changed as `NaN`.

How can I keep it in the same format.

I tried to do this way.

`df` is initial dataframe and after that

```
df2 = df.astype(object).where(pd.notnull(df), None)
```

but with this some columns values are getting changed to decimals.

Comment: For me your solution works in sample data. But it is a little hack, so it should be buggy with some specific data

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that pandas will detect the column as int but, since there is NULL values, it will put those values as NaN. 
NaN values in pandas / numpy are typed as `float`, so the whole column will be casted as float.
If you want to recast to int, you should cast the non-NaN values like this:

```
df.ix[~pd.isnull(df["column"]),"column"] = df.loc[~pd.isnull(df["column"])]["column"].astype(int)
```